# Query to merge 2 tables , not sure if this is a full outer join

Tags: sql, database, join

I have 2 tables that I'm not sure how to join correctly. One table lists my employees and the hours they worked, the other lists the same employees and the hours we scheduled them to work at the beginning of the year. I'd like to see each employee along with the scheduled vs actual for each project they were either assigned to or worked.

TABLE 1 scheduled hours table

```
Name, Project, Scheduled_Hours
------------------------------------------------
Alice    B      1
Bob      A      1
Bob      B      1
```

TABLE 2 Actual Hours worked table

```
Name, Project, Actual_Hours
------------------------------------------------
Alice    A      1
Bob      B      1
```

RESULT I WANT Scheduled vs Actual Combined table - what I'd like to produce

```
Name,   Project, Scheduled_Hours, Actual_Hours
------------------------------------------------
Alice   A         Null             1
Alice   B         1                NULL
Bob     A         1                NULL
Bob     B         1                1
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed a `full join` on the name and project.

The syntax slightly varies across databases - and not all of the support `full join`. The most portable query would be:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) name,
    coalesce(t1.project, t2.project) project,
    t1.scheduled_hours,
    t2.actual_hours
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 
    on t2.name = t1.name and t2.project = t1.project
```

Some databases support the `using` clause, which shortens the syntax a little:

```
select 
    name,
    project,
    t1.scheduled_hours,
    t2.actual_hours
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 
    using (name, project)
```